# Can I state that every linearly independent set of vectors that is independent in V and of length equal to dimension of V span the whole V?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I know that

(A) if a set of vectors is linearly independent in vector space V and span the whole V, then this set forms a basis for V.

But I'm curious... (B) For a set to be basis, isn't it enough for this set to be independent and have length equal to dimension of V?

Comment: Assuming the right context, I think the two statements (which you give) are equivalent.

Comment: @peter.petrov, it's just a definition from my lectures on linear algebra: A set of vectors S in v.s. V is called a basis if S is linearly independent and S spans V.

Comment: @peter.petrov. In the lecture it is mentioned as a definition

Comment: OK, yes, this is a definition, sorry. And what you say as a statement is also true, it can be used as alternative definition (or you can prove it from the definition they gave you).

Comment: @peter.petrov. Thanks, just found the way how to prove it

Comment: A is your definition. You can prove B from A. Or ... if you want you can take B as definition and prove A. That happens sometimes in math. But in this case A is definitely the more general/classical definition.

Comment: (B) is correct provided the dimension of $V$ is finite.